# Does Solace load balance LDAP requests to all the registered LDAP servers?

Tags: solace

I have registered 3 LDAP Servers in Solace for client authentication using LDAP protocol.  I understand that Solace creates a connection pool to handle requests to one of the LDAP Servers.  But, I wonder whether the other two LDAP Servers are being used for load balancing purposes (meaning Solace will send LDAP requests to them in the event that the first one is overloaded) or only for backup purposes in case the first one is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The additional LDAP servers are configurable for redundancy purposes. The Solace PubSub+ message broker will attempt to connect to the LDAP server in the order of preference based off of the index number. Once connected, the message broker continues to use this connection to authenticate clients until the connection goes down. (e.g. timeout from the far end or a shutdown of the LDAP profile).

Comment: So, to cater for high volume of LDAP authentication requests, I need to put an LB in front of my LDAP Servers (assuming I have many of them) and register only the LB IP address as the LDAP Server IP in Solace?